# Does the current version of Tor work with Citrix/terminal services?

Tags: configuration, server

I have tried in the past to use Tor in multi user environments like Citrix but it only worked for one user at a time. Has this changed with later versions? If not does anyone know if it could be looked into?

Answer (score 1):

Tor can be used for several users at a time. Run Tor as daemon if you want, then you can proceed to run any network/internet software through Tor socks proxy:

`torsocks *software*`

For options about configuring and customizing the torsocks proxy, you can consult the `torrc` config file.